# TYPE command. Inserting csv file

Tags: sql, shell, csv, t-sql, command-prompt

I have a CSV file im looking to load into a TSQL table using the "type" command.

Code: type yourfilename

When looking in the command prompt its breaking the file lines into two different rows and inserting them separately into my destination table

EX.

```
  "Manheim Chicago","Manheim","IL","199004520601","On
   Block","2D4FV47V86H126473","2006","DODGE","MAGNUM 4X2 V6"
```

I want solution to look like this

[Solution Pic 
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkgf6.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGIec.png)

Where this would be one record in the table.

Question.  Does anyone know how to format a type command so it displays a full record without line breaks?

Comment: the code  `type yourfilename` will display the content on the command prompt (and thus, maybe breaking lines because of the maximum length per line). Where do you actually put into your SQLServer database ? Do you copy-paste the line from the command prompt ?

Comment: im inserting straight into the destination table from the type command, but was looking to see if i could increase the maximum length per line??

Comment: When you say "command prompt", you mean the CMD.EXE Windows shell, right ? Could you try on Powershell instead by using `Get-Content yourfilename` (or `cat yourfilename`, which is a default alias of this command)

Comment: And of course resize your powershell window so it's large enough to contain the line

Comment: ive never worked in powershell so not sure how to use it or resize powershell window

Comment: Like any other window, really. You click on the corner with the mouse and drag it.